# Unable to Publish Angular 2 SPA with .Net core 2.0 Visual Studio Community 2017

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

when I try to ftp publish my SPA website using the Visual Studio 2017 publish option I get the following error;

> Error     The command "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod" exited with code 2.

If I look at my output I get the following detail;

```
ERROR in ./ClientApp/boot.server.ts
Module not found(0,0): Error : Can't resolve './../$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/app.server.module.ngfactory' in 'C:\Users\matt\Source\Repos\braehead\braehead\ClientApp'
         @ ./ClientApp/boot.server.ts 8:0-94
        Child ClientApp\app\components\app\app.component.html:
             1 asset
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what it this error means please?

I have looked at the following link, [Adding an Angular library makes the publish process fail](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1293) However, I cannot find the referenced text in my webpack.config.js

Comment: I have the same issue when publishing my SPAs based on the Angular 2 template. For the time being, I'd dropped the `--env.prod` from the effected line in the csproj/sln files. It does mean that my SPAs aren't built in prod, but they're not public facing, so it's fine as a temporary fix

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and in order to resolve this one I did the following changes

1. I run the following command in command prompt(right click on the project and then choose power command-->open command prompt )
   dotnet build --configuration Release
2. Change value const isDevBuild = true;//!(env && env.prod); under webpack.config.js

Now publish the project and you will get a message WebApp was published successfully.

Thanks